# Faster Evaluating IF Condition of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement

Back to the basics of JavaScript. This is a question I am coming with is based on computation time speed of JavaScript If condition.

I have a logic which includes usage of if condition. The question is computing equal to value is faster OR not equal to value is faster?

```
if(vm.currentFeedbackObject.sendReminderLists[0].sendReminderFlag !== '' && vm.currentFeedbackObject.sendReminderLists[0].sendReminderedOn !== null)
            {
              vm.isReminderSectionVisible = true;
            } else
            {
              vm.isReminderSectionVisible = false;
            }
```

The above one computes **not equal to**

```
if(vm.currentFeedbackObject.sendReminderLists[0].sendReminderFlag === '' && vm.currentFeedbackObject.sendReminderLists[0].sendReminderedOn === null)
            {
              vm.isReminderSectionVisible = false;
            } else
            {
              vm.isReminderSectionVisible = true;
            }
```

The above one computes **equal to value**

which of both these is faster in execution?

Comment: why do you need this? take a look into the ASM compiler if you need speed. Generally speaking microoptimizing javascript is a waste of time because things the JIT does supercede whatever little tricks there are out there.

Comment: What makes you think there is any difference in speed? And what makes you think it matters? And why don't you measure it to find out? Also, why is your indentation so bizarre? Your code is hard to read.

Comment: I am making a native feel like app and every optimization counts. Hence the question.

Comment: Possibly worth noting here that an empty javascript string resolves to null (more accurately, both will return false), so you're making two checks when you only really need one.

Comment: In the hierarchy of coding priorities, clear, clean and easy to maintain code come far before performance in nearly all cases.  Write your code whichever way is the easiest to understand and the most logical and then only worry about performance when you have a measured performance issue that needs addressing.  Then, you can benchmark your exact case in a number of different browsers to investigate how to speed it up.  Premature optimization fights all the other coding priorities.

Comment: @lucas - an empty string doesn't resolve to `null`.  It resolves to `falsey` when compared in a plain `if` statement.

Comment: You should measure it yourself : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: Also, there are plenty ways to write this : Early returning if condition is true  then returning false by default, setting the variable directly with the condition as value, ... So it's pretty difficult to see what is more efficient here.

Comment: It seems you already have established yourself that **the two snippets do different things**. So choosing one should be based on functionality, not on speed?! Use the **correct** one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try it out? Write to your console this:

```
function notequal() {
  if(vm.currentFeedbackObject.sendReminderLists[0].sendReminderFlag !== ''    && vm.currentFeedbackObject.sendReminderLists[0].sendReminderedOn !== null)

    vm.isReminderSectionVisible = true;
  } 
  else {
    vm.isReminderSectionVisible = false;
  }
}

function yesequal() {
  if(vm.currentFeedbackObject.sendReminderLists[0].sendReminderFlag === ''    && vm.currentFeedbackObject.sendReminderLists[0].sendReminderedOn === null)
    vm.isReminderSectionVisible = false;
  } 
  else {
    vm.isReminderSectionVisible = true;
  }
}

var iterations = 1000000; 
console.time('Notequal #1');
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    notequal();
};
console.timeEnd('Notequal #1')

console.time('Yesequal #2');
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    yesequal();
};
console.timeEnd('Yesequal #2')
```

Comment: This performance api helps too if you need millisecond precision :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now